# Set template directory using Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, slim

Using Slim Framework 2 you could set the template directory using this code:

```
// Views
$view = $app->view();
$view->setTemplateDirectory('../app/views');
```

How can I do this using Slim Framework 3?

Currently I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplateDirectory() on null
```

Does anybody know how to do this in Slim Framework 3?

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation?

Comment: Yes. But I'm following a tutorial that is written in Slim 2. So far I'm able to convert everything to Slim 3 but can't seem to get this one.

Comment: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using a `\Slim\Container` instance:

```
// Create container
$container = new \Slim\Container;

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('your/path/to/templates');
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $c['router'],
        $c['request']->getUri()
    ));

    return $view;
};
```

Then you can use it:

```
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

// The route
$app->get('/foo', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {
  return $this->view->render($response, 'index.html', [
        'name' => 'name'
    ]);
});
$app->run();
```

Check the [official documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html) ([Mika Tuupola's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461768/set-template-directory-using-slim-framework-3#comment56670632_34461768)).